# Merge data from different rows in one cell

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help storing the names of purchased products from the same Order ID in 1 cell (Trying to output the obtained data to excel file). Example:

Products Order Table:

```
orders_id  |  products_name
100        |  LCD Monitor
101        |  Laptop Intel Processor
101        |  Gaming Keyboard
```

Expected output

```
orders_id  |  products_name
100        |  LCD Monitor
101        |  Laptop Intel Processor<br>Gaming Keyboad
```

PHP code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders_products";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>  
        <td align="left">'.$row["orders_id"].'</td>
        <td align="left">'.$row["products_name"].'</td>
    </tr>
   ';
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `GROUP BY orders_id` and see what you get.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I get only 1 of the ordered products, not both. I think I should insert another loop inside WHILE, when the orders_id is the same.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) alongside GROUP BY to get the expected result:

```
SELECT 
    orders_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT products_name ORDER BY products_name ASC SEPARATOR ' <br> '
    ) AS products_name
FROM 
    orders_products 
GROUP BY orders_id;
```